# Object doesn't support this property or method ( ie8 jquery v1.11.1 )

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have written a small script that highlights a different event (div) every 3 seconds. This works fine on firefox chrome safari but on ie8-ie10 it doesn't run.

When I go into the developertools and debug the script I get the error Object doesn't support this property or method.
It stops after this line

```
var status = jQuery(".home-event-images").css("display");
```

The complete script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){           
    rotate();
});

var cnt=1;

function rotate() {
    var status = jQuery(".home-event-images").css("display");    
    if (status === 'block') {
        if (cnt < 2) {
            cnt++;
        } else {
            cnt = 0;
        }

        if (cnt === 0) {
            jQuery(".home-event-listing1").removeClass("home-event-listing-active");  
            jQuery(".home-event-listing2").addClass("home-event-listing-active");
            jQuery(".home-event-image-active").removeClass("home-event-image-active");
            jQuery(".home-events-image2").addClass("home-event-image-active");
        }   

        if (cnt === 1) {
            jQuery(".home-event-listing2").removeClass("home-event-listing-active");  
            jQuery(".home-event-listing3").addClass("home-event-listing-active");
            jQuery(".home-event-image-active").removeClass("home-event-image-active");
            jQuery(".home-events-image3").addClass("home-event-image-active");
        }   

        if (cnt === 2) {
            jQuery(".home-event-listing3").removeClass("home-event-listing-active");  
            jQuery(".home-event-listing1").addClass("home-event-listing-active");
            jQuery(".home-event-image-active").removeClass("home-event-image-active");
            jQuery(".home-events-image1").addClass("home-event-image-active");
        }   
    } else {
        cnt=1;
        jQuery(".home-event-listing1").removeClass("home-event-listing-active");  
        jQuery(".home-event-image-active").removeClass("home-event-image-active");
        jQuery(".home-event-listing2").removeClass("home-event-listing-active");  
        jQuery(".home-event-image-active").removeClass("home-event-image-active");
        jQuery(".home-event-listing3").removeClass("home-event-listing-active");  
        jQuery(".home-event-image-active").removeClass("home-event-image-active");
    }
    setTimeout(rotate(),3500);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This doesn't look right `setTimeout(rotate(),3500);`. You'd want to pass the function as an argument, not execute it.

Comment: `setTimeout(rotate,3500);`

Comment: Thanks elclanrs and Arun. That worked (and yes i feel a bit stupid ;)